# Showing images stored in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm actually having some difficulty understanding how to do this.
Before I used to have the images stored right in the server, but moving to production I decided to take this way. So, after storing it in bucket `example` how exactly should I fetch the picture `19512491.jpg` and displaying it in the source?

`<img src="image_src_should_go_here"/>`

I'm I supposed to edit permission in the bucket and allow permission to read the contents in a given folder, or else? Thank you very much...

Answer (score 10):

**The IMG link**

First, you would construct a URL that points to the image in Amazon S3.

The exact URL may change depending upon the region in use (see [Amazon S3 Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region)). It would look something like this:

```
https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/BUCKET-NAME/image.jpg
```

If you have configured your bucket as a Static Website, the URL would look like:

```
https://s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/BUCKET-NAME/image.jpg
```

So, you'd use it in an `IMG` tag, like this:

```
<img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/BUCKET-NAME/image.jpg"/>
```

**Security**

You can either make the object **publicly accessible**, or use a **Pre-Signed URL**.

The easiest way to make the object publicly accessible is to use a **Bucket Policy** such as this one (from the [Amazon S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2)) that makes the whole bucket public:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The policy can, of course, be more selective such as only making a particular directory public.

Alternatively, if you wish to be more selective, you could keep your objects in Amazon S3 private and then have your application generate a **Pre-Signed URL** that provides authenticated access to an object for a specific time period.

This is a great way to give selective access to files. For example, if you operate a photo-sharing site like Flickr, you could serve private pictures to owners

See documentation: [Share an Object with Others](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: The Security section helped me get started and I will be not allowing public access in the future but also the url that worked for me was `https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<location>`